# How to extract full object from Dictionary<string, object> using key,value pairs

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have been struggeling with this issue for some time now. Basically i have a
`Dictionary<string, object>` with some values whitch represent a type. `Person` for example.

This is my base class:

```
Public class Person
{
   private string _name;
   private string _lastname;
   private Adress _adress;

   public Person()
   {
   }


   public string Name
   {
      get{ return this._name; }
      set{ this._name = value; }
   }

   public string LastName
   {
      get{ return this._lastname; }
      set{ this._lastname = value; }
   }

   public Adress HomeAdress
   {
      get{ return this._adress; }
      set{ this._adress = value; }
   }

}
```

---

Than i have some other class where i would like to construct this `Person` object from the values within my `Dictionary<string, object>` variable.

```
Private Person person;

Dictionary<string, object> test(Dictionary<string,object>)dictionary.GetValueOrDefault(nameof(person), null);

Type type = typeof(Person);
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        foreach (var kv in test)
        {
             type.GetProperty(kv.Key).SetValue(obj, kv.Value);
        }

        this.person= (Person)obj;
```

However, The adress property in Person is an Object and cannot be converted to Adress like that. So how do i go about this without having to write countless `if()` statements for determining whitch type is required for the Cast.

The bottom line is to have this `Person` object populated with the values from the `Dictionary<string, object>`. This dictionary is populated. and has values in it. I didn't post all code for the filling of the Dictionary because i didn't want to make it confusing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what kind of problem you have with your code. Please provide error details and some code to reproduce that error

Comment: you want to read the address object from person object right ? and put it in other variable ?

Comment: well its a very abstract thing to explain really. this dictionary. contains all the information to make a Person variable from it. however im struggeling with converting / reading / extracting.. whatever you want to call it. From this dictionary. With strings this is no problem. But as soon as another type is used. that is not a base type like string, int or bool. it crashes, saying it can't convert object -> to Adress

Comment: and i was looking for a way to dynamically cast to the type that should be used in the foreach loop

i want to go from Dictionary<string, object>  --> to Person

Comment: Your example code doesn't compile and makes no sense. Dictionary doesn't have a method named GetValueOrDefault(). That entire line isn't valid C# at all. Please provide a code sample which compiles. What is `test` supposed to be?

Comment: it doesn't compile because it doesn't have all classes in my sample. Im just looking for a way to convert Dictionary --> person

Comment: Is it the case that your dictionary contains entries similar to this: Name = "Bob"; LastName = "Smith"; HomeAddress = {instance of Address class}?

Comment: @Serge Yes thats very possible

Comment: @downvoter why the downvote? Just because you can't answer doesn't mean its a bad question...

Comment: @Feddex I told you one reason why your code doesn’t compile. There are others. The missing “Adress” class isn’t the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a nested dictionary with dictionaries you could solve it by taking a detour by serializing the dictionary to JSON and then deserialize the JSON to a Person object.

An example using JSON.NET:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"Name", "Erik"},
    {"HomeAddress", new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"Street", "Foo"}
    }}
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
```

Comment: Yes! that did the trick! Thank you so much. I have been looking for a solution for this for hours!